# Modal operator mouse over event

Tags: python, modeling, scripting, add-on, operator

I'm working on an addon that generates buildings based upon a base mesh.

Presently, I'm hoping to add a feature that allows the user to very quickly create the base mesh using a modal operator, whereby they would be able to extrude the base mesh in fixed increments by clicking and dragging the faces they want to extrude.

I want the operator to check if the mouse cursor is over a face on the base object, and set that face as the active selection. Anyone done something like this before? Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated!

(Note: If there's a more efficient means to the same end, I'm very open to suggestions!)

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise, not quite, but that's pretty cool! I could think of quite a few applications for a tool like that. The tool I'm working on will be primarily for the purpose of creating individual buildings. It was something I needed to do to help speed along the development of a game project, but I decided to keep going to make a fully-featured addon! In the end, the user will be able to generate custom textured buildings with baked AO and textures ready for export in to a game engine!